# How to avoid getting page number as a string using slim framework?

Tags: php, slim

I am using slim 2.x framework for developing a web service. When I use 'get' request method its working fine but all the parameters getting are string. I want 'page' parameter as a numeric value. How to change this in slim. Below is my code.

```
$app->get('/listings','getListings');
/* Run the application */
$app->run();

function getListings(){
global $api_obj;//api obj
$response = array();//array
$app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();
$req = $app->request;
$page = $req->get('page');
$response = $api_obj->api_Listings($page); //return
echoResponse(200, $response);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a simple cast to get the integer from it:

```
$page = (int)$req->get('page');

//or

$page = intval($req->get('page'));
```

Ex: https://3v4l.org/cUqVA

Comment: tried both, still no result but when adding page no as  static its working fine. ex. `$response = $api_obj->api_Listings(10);`

Comment: yes its a working method. But in slim framework i don't know what is wrong with it?

Comment: This is not a problem with slim framework but rather a problem with how PHP type juggles.